# Missing symbols from FDGC symbols in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

Problem: FDGC geologic symbols appear as question marks in QGIS

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and QGIS 3.20 and my geologic symbols now appear as `?`.

[image]

I tried following directions for converting .eps to .svg found at:
[Procedure_for_creating_SVG_files_for_use_in_QGIS_from_FGDC_symbols](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335601349_Procedure_for_creating_SVG_files_for_use_in_QGIS_from_FGDC_symbols)

But when I open files in Inkscape, I get a similar result:

[image]

I replicated with files downloaded from two different sources:
https://pubs.usgs.gov/tm/2006/11A02/
https://sourceforge.net/projects/qgisgeologysymbology/files/

This makes me think something is missing at a deeper level in my system, so I installed the .pfm and .fon 'FGDCGeoAge' fonts into \Windows\Fonts

Then, I restarted both Inkscape and QGIS but to the same result.

PS. Previously, these were working just fine in Windows 10 and QGIS 3.16.